# How to control primary key in datagridview with c#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datatables

I am developing window c# application. I have data entry grid view and binding data with data table. The table from SQL database has primary key. In grid view, the primary key is working in behind. I used DefaultValuesNeeded event for primary key. It is okay. But it is not okay when I click on cell of new row or grid view combo and input some value in some cell and delete that value. And when I move the cursor to another row, the new row in grid view is disappeared but in behind, the primary key is null and getting error primary key can't insert null into the table. So help me please how to control primary key in grid view when I direct access to grid view. Thanks you.
P.S I don't want to use text box or combo box and add button to add data row to grid view and I want to play mouse cursor in grid view whatever I want. I want to direct input entry to grid view. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the grid view with primary key as 1st hidden column, whenever you try to update,delete does record pass the hidden column value with it, In case of delete, after success DML operation delete that row of grid view

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sandeep. But I don't understand clearly what you mean. I think, I already bind data to grid view when the form loaded. Like that dt = get table from db(Select *  From table) and bs.datasource = dt and dgv.datasource = bs. I don't know your DML short term. Thanks.